# php session_id algorithm without session?

Tags: php

Is it possible to generate PHP session IDs easily without actually `session_start()`ing?

For example:

```
mk_session_id() //=> fafhasjkldfh890523ejl
```

I know that there are other ways of making similar things, but I'd like to match the PHP session id format.

Answer (score 0):

Not in my opinion, at least not with session function in standart PHP. You can only generate an session ID manually with `session_regenerate_id`. However, this does just update the current session id with a newly generated one.

However (I am sure you know that), you can generat such ID's by some random string generator keeping the lenght, characters etc just as the php generated sessions have.