# How is the PHP session_id() value calculated?

Tags: php, database, http, session, cookies

Before marking this question as a duplicate to [php session_id algorithm without session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755146/php-session-id-algorithm-without-session), I need to ask this...

currently I use session_id() to retrieve a value that is assigned to a user and store it in a database.

This link has more info on session_id(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

Later I found out that I can create my own configuration into a single cookie of smaller size than the size of a standard PHP session cookie when I check the HTTP header response from the pages in both cases.

I also found out to use session_id(), sessions need to be started (can be called via session_start()), but every time one is started, PHP creates a session cookie along with other cookies I send, making the HTTP header response bigger.

In order to keep things consistent with the data in the database, how does PHP calculate the value returned from session_id()? I want to write my own function to replace it.

Comment: You would have to look at the php source code for that I believe.

Comment: if the handfull of extra bytes is an issue, you have bigger problems

Answer (score 2):

You can find the **entire source** for that function [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/session.c#L1507). It's the latest version though, so be wary of any differences from your PHP version.